# Why can’t I say “We are prepared to hear the other 23 speeches” instead of “We are prepared to hear other 23 speeches”?

Tags: meaning, word-usage, meaning-in-context, american-english

Since other is for plural, I thought that instead of saying

A) We are prepared to hear another 23 speeches.

I could just simply say

B) We are prepared to hear the other 23 speeches.

I notice that if I wanted to write the same sentence without the ”the” before ”other” it may be incorrect.

Why is that?

Answer (score 2):

Both are correct. It depends on what you are trying to say.

"The other" implies that there are already exactly 23 other speeches prepared.

"Another" implies that there could be any number more speeches and you are prepared to listed to only (or up to) 23 more.

Please also note that your title and main text do not align.

> We are prepared to hear other 23 speeches.

Does not make sense, but I believe this is just a typo. However, if not then you could change the word order:

> We are prepared to hear 23 other speeches.